# How to make cgroup V2 persist accross system reboot in RHEL 7

Tags: rhel, filesystems, mount, reboot, cgroups

I am using RHEL 7. The default Cgroup hierarchy for the system is Cgroup V1.
I need the system to have both Cgroup V1 and Cgroup V2 hierarchies co-existing, and I am achieving that by manually creating root Cgroup V2 via

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/cgroup2
sudo mount -t cgroup2 none /mnt/cgroup2/
```

Hence, the system currently have default Cgroup V1 hierarchy at `/sys/fs/cgroup`
and cgroup V2 hierarchy at `/mnt/cgroup2`

But, on system reboot the Cgroup V2 mount point goes away. The directory stays, but the Cgroup V2 filesystem is not mounted there anymore.

Before reboot

```
$ mount | grep cgroup2
none on /mnt/cgroup2 type cgroup2 (rw,relatime,seclabel)
```

After reboot

```
$ mount | grep cgroup2
<---- no output . Hence mount is gone
$ ls /mnt/cgroup2
<---- no ls error. Hence directory stays
$
```

How can I make Cgroup V2 persist accross reboots in my system ?

One approach is to setup some boot script or cron job, to mount Cgroup V2 hierarchy whenever system boots. But that does not seems a good approach.

Also, I cant replace Cgroup V1 filesystem which it mounted at  `/sys/fs/cgroup` . Both Cgroup V1 and Cgroup V2 should coexist in the system.

Edit -
Current mounts for cgroup V1 and V2

```
$ mount | grep cgroup
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,seclabel,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,xattr,release_agent=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,net_cls,net_prio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,hugetlb)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,perf_event)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/pids type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,pids)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,memory)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/rdma type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,rdma)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,freezer)
uc on /uc/cgroups type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,name=uc)
none on /mnt/cgroup2 type cgroup2 (rw,relatime,seclabel)
```

Edit 2 - Updated mount directory from /run/cgroup2 to /mnt/cgroup2

Comment: Are you sure it's RHEL 7? AFAIK cgroup-v2 support was only added to RHEL 8.

Comment: Yes. Its Oracle Linux 7.6, which is RHEL 7. I am not sure about this, but I assume that RHEL 8 supports using Cgroup V2 as the default cgroup hierarchy ( in `/sys/fs/cgroup` ) . While RHEL 7 does not. In RHEL 7 you can have Cgroup V2 heirarchy mounted at some place other than `/sys/fs/cgroup`